# What is wrong with this code?

Tags: arduino-mega, pwm, remote-control, compilation-errors

So I am writing code to control a servo with an RC radio. I am using an Arduino Mega.  I get this error whenever I compile.  I am not that experienced with Arduino so I am probably not doing something right. Thanks for the help!

> Arduino: 1.8.5 (Windows 10), Board: "Arduino/Genuino Mega or Mega
>   2560, ATmega2560 (Mega 2560)"
>
> C:\Users\ethan\Desktop\Periferals_control\Periferals_control.ino: In
>   function 'void loop()':
>
> Periferals_control:46: error: expected ';' before '{' token
>
> {
>
> ^
>
> exit status 1 expected ';' before '{' token
>
> This report would have more information with "Show verbose output
>   during compilation" option enabled in File -> Preferences.

```
#include <Servo.h>
Servo servo1;
Servo servo2;
//the following are all ~PWM capable ports
int servoElevator_PwmIn = 6; //Elevator Servo
int servoGrabber_PwmIn = 7; //Grabber Servo

//Channels on AT9
int leftStickVertical = 2; //Channel 3
int rightStickVertical = 3; //Channel 7


int elevatorServoStop = 50;

void setup() {

  //pinMode(servoGrabber_PwmIn, OUTPUT);
  //pinMode(servoElevator_PwmIn, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(leftStickVertical, INPUT);
  pinMode(rightStickVertical, INPUT);
  Serial.begin(9600);

  servo1.attach(6);
  servo2.attach(servoGrabber_PwmIn);
}

void loop() {

  int leftStickVerticalPwm = pulseIn(leftStickVertical, HIGH, 25000);
  int rightStickVerticalPwm = pulseIn(rightStickVertical, HIGH, 25000);
  Serial.print(leftStickVerticalPwm);
  Serial.print("\t");
  Serial.print(rightStickVerticalPwm);
  Serial.print("\n");


  if (rightStickVerticalPwm == 0)
  {
    servo1.write(elevatorServoStop);
  }
  else if (rightStickVerticalPwm > 1500)
  {
    servo1.write(100);
  }
  else (rightStickVerticalPwm < 1400)
  {
    servo1.write(30);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```cpp
  if (rightStickVerticalPwm == 0)
  {
    servo1.write(elevatorServoStop);
  }
  else if (rightStickVerticalPwm > 1500)
  {
    servo1.write(100);
  }
  else (rightStickVerticalPwm < 1400)
  {
    servo1.write(30);
  }
```

You cannot have another comparison in an `else` statement. You might have meant `else if` in the last clause.

Clarification if you're not well familiar with C/C++: If you have an `if` statement, it can be followed by arbitrary many `else if` clauses and at maximum one `else` clause which will execute when all other conditions fail. For example:

```cpp
 int a = 10;
 if( a == 9 ) {
       //Executed if a = 9
 } else if( a < 20 ) {
   //If above not executed, this will be executed if a < 20
 } else { 
   //This is executed if none of the conditions above hold.
   //A pure "else" does not have a condition and only one may 
   //exist in an `if` statement.
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

you should not provide conditions for " else " statement because it focuses on what action should happen if all " if and else if " conditions are not fulfiiled.